# Arbitrary Tuple of enums

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I have an enumeration `RankAndFile` with 64 values representing the squares on a chessboard.

I would like a obtain a ScalaCheck `Arbitrary[(RankAndFile, RankAndFile)]` but I'm not sure how.

So far I have:

```
implicit val arbitraryRankAndFile = 
  Arbitrary(Gen.oneOf(RankAndFile.values.toSeq))

implicit val arbitraryRankAndFilePair = 
  Arbitrary.arbTuple2[RankAndFile, RankAndFile]
```

But the compiler complains on the second statement that it `could not find implicit value for parameter a1: org.scalacheck.Arbitrary[RankAndFile.RankAndFile]`. Certainly this is because the type of `arbitraryRankAndFile` is `Arbitrary[Gen[RankAndFile]]`.

What should I have instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arbitrary single value was enough:

```
implicit def rankAndFile = Arbitrary { Gen.oneOf(RankAndFile.values.toSeq) }
```

The property to be checked took a tuple of `RankAndFile` which could be satisfied by scalacheck from this single `Arbitrary` value. The method `Arbitrary.arbTuple2` was a red-herring.